# How to push a new scene using react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm creating a react-native application and I'm using it for navigation react-navigation.

I'm trying to get the following behavior:

Have the main Drawer menu, if I navigate to an item from Drawer, the drawer should close, navigate to the scene and have the same navbar for all items in the drawer.
In one item I have a tab navigator.

I actual implementation the only problem is: the drawer is not closing on item click. Any suggestion?

And if I navigate from a scene to another scene (this scene is not a drawer item), I can navigate to that scene but my header (navbar) is not changing and I don't have the back button. Any suggestion?

This is what I have done for the moment, but is not working as expected.

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createSwitchNavigator,
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createMaterialTopTabNavigator,
} from "react-navigation";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";
import { AppConfig } from "../constants";
import { AppSizes, AppColors } from "../theme";

import DrawerMenu from "./drawerMenu";
// import DrawerScreen from './DrawerScreen'

// Scenes
import LaunchContainer from "../containers/Launch";
import LoginContainer from "../containers/Login";
import HomeContainer from "../containers/Home";
import RoomsHistoryContainer from "../containers/RoomsHistory";
import LogoutContainer from "../containers/Logout";
import ChatContainer from "../containers/Chat";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  iconStyle: {
    marginLeft: 10,
  },
});

const TabStack = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Conversation: {
      screen: RoomsHistoryContainer,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Conversatii",
      },
    },
    Comunitate: {
      screen: LaunchContainer,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Comunitate",
      },
    },
    Chatroom: {
      screen: LaunchContainer,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Chatroom",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      style: {
        backgroundColor: AppColors.tabbar.background,
      },
      activeTintColor: AppColors.tabbar.activeTintColor,
      inactiveTintColor: AppColors.tabbar.inactiveTintColor,
      indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor: AppColors.tabbar.indicatorColor,
      },
    },
  }
);

const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeContainer },
    Calendar: { screen: LaunchContainer },
    Comunitate: {
      screen: TabStack,
      navigationOptions: { title: "Comunitate" },
    },
    Logout: { screen: LogoutContainer },
    ChatMessage: { screen: ChatContainer },
  },
  {
    headerMode: "float",
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      ...AppConfig.navbarProps,
      title: "My app",
      headerLeft: (
        <Icon
          name="menu"
          containerStyle={styles.iconStyle}
          color="#fff"
          size={30}
          onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
        />
      ),
    }),
  }
);

const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Main: { screen: AppStack },
  },
  {
    contentComponent: DrawerMenu,
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "white",
      activeBackgroundColor: "white",
    },
    drawerWidth: AppSizes.screen.width > 250 ? AppSizes.screen.width - 80 : 250,
  }
);

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    SignIn: {
      screen: LoginContainer,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Login",
      },
    },
    SignUp: {
      screen: LoginContainer,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Logout",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    headerMode: "none",
  }
);

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Launch: { screen: LaunchContainer },
    App: { screen: DrawerStack },
    Auth: { screen: AuthStack },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Launch",
  }
);

export default AppNavigator;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Close drawer when use navigate

Simply, call drawer close method before naviagate.

```
this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();
this.props.navigation.naviagte('ANOTHER_SCREEN');
```

#### Show `BackButton` on Header in React Navigation

`BackButton` is shown only `StackNavigation` after `push` or `navigate` from another screen which is in same `StackNavigation`. Thus,

- Check your screen's position. Is it the screen component in `StackNavigation`?
- Is it moved in from another screen which is in same `StackNavigation`?
- Is your Header mode right in `navigationOptions`?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Navigation drawer not closing**

This is unusual, if everything is correct in your custom drawer component, it should work. But you can always use `this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();`

**2. Back button is not showing**

I assume this is happening in AppStack. Your code looks fine. Be sure to use `this.props.navigation.navigate(screenName)`. If pressing hardware back button goes to previous screen, then stack navigation is working good. So the problem is in your header rendering. I would recommend to remove all the custom options for now and just try with a simple `createStackNavigator` without any navigations options. This is the first step to point out the root cause of your problem.